# How can I emulate the check-in-with friend feature via the Foursquare API?

Tags: api, foursquare, checkin

According to [this support page](http://support.foursquare.com/entries/23278742-Mentioning-friends-in-check-ins), by mentioning a friend in a checkin shout, you will cause that friend to be checked-in with you. However, when I [POST to /v2/checkins/add](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/add) and include well-formed 'shout' and 'mentions' parameters, it only tells my friends that I mentioned them in my check-in, as opposed to triggering a delegated check-in (like the native mobile apps are capable of doing).

Querying [/v2/checkins/CHECKIN_ID](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/checkins) reveals that the checkins created by the API are completely missing the 'with' field, while it is present in checkins created by the official apps.

How can I populate the 'with' field via the API?

Comment: Does the user you're trying to check in have the option toggled to allow check-ins by others?

Comment: Yes, they definitely have that toggled.

Comment: Bump, any news on this one?

Comment: @user2660000 Nope. I assume the guys at Foursquare have been busy with the recent rollout of Swarm. I also haven't tried again since there's nothing in the documentation to suggest that this would work. When I get some time I want to proxy my phone to see what their native app sends when you checkin with someone.